# R CMD check error : How to change file permission on windows?

Tags: r, windows, cmd

I have R CMD check error for my R packages, and error most possibly because of file permission set up wrong on my machine. I searched related post in SO but some of them is confusing. some people implied that run R CMD check supposed to be happen in directory where I have write permission, I can't figure how to rightly configure this on machine. Can any one help me how to change the file permission on windows ? How to solve this R CMD check error ?

- Note

This is where R installed : `C:\Program Files\R\R-devel\bin\x64\Rgui.exe"`

This is where my package located :`C:\Users\jvrat\Documents\MSPC`

Here is the session of running R CMD check :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jvrat>cd C:\Program Files\R\R-devel\bin\x64

C:\Program Files\R\R-devel\bin\x64>R CMD check "C:\Users\jvrat\Documents\MSPC"
Warning in dir.create(pkgoutdir, mode = "0755") :
  cannot create dir 'C:\Program Files\R\R-devel\bin\x64\MSPC.Rcheck', reason 'Permission denied'
ERROR: cannot create check dir 'C:/Program Files/R/R-devel/bin/x64/MSPC.Rcheck'

C:\Program Files\R\R-devel\bin\x64>
```

which folder that I need to change file permission ? How can I make this happen file permission configuration on windows ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Right click however you start your program and choose Run As Administrator.

Comment: Change the current directory to your user directory (where you have write permission) and run R with explicit path. In your case it is: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-devel\bin\x64\R" CMD check ...`

Comment: @Noodles yes, it worked if I opened CMD as administrator.

Comment: @bergant If I tried your solution, I got error like this : 
C:\Users\jvrat>cd C:\Program Files\R\R-devel\bin\x64\R\
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Note the quoting ("...") in my solution (because there is a space in your path, windows interprets the first word as a program call)